# branch.io deepview is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, deep-linking, branch.io

We have a mobile site and we are trying to utilize our mobile pages for deepview using branch.io.

We followed the steps mentioned in the following link: https://dev.branch.io/features/website-to-app-routing/guide/

We created a new url with only 1 parameter, i.e., $fallback_url = www.xxx.com/a/b and embedded the following js code in our angular js mobile website. Our android URI schema is abc://a?x=y

We added branch.io web sdk in the head tag and added the following script in script tag.

```
// load the Branch SDK file
branch.init('Test_key', function(data) {});
// define the deepview structure
branch.deepview({
  'channel': 'mobile_web',
  'feature': 'deepview',
  data: {
    '$deeplink_path': 'a?x=y'
  }
}, {
  'open_app': true // If true, Branch attempts to open your app immediately when the page loads. If false, users will need to press a button. Defaults to true
}, function() {
  branch.deepviewCta();
  console.log('callback');
});
```

now the issue is that the mobile site gets loaded properly, but when it tries to open mobile app after the webpage load, it tries the redirection with url as "intent://open?branch_link=zzzz" instead of the schema mentioned in the deeplink_url variable.

Pls help.

Answer (score 0):

Alex from Branch.io here:

**This is the correct, expected behavior for Branch links**.

Branch links work as storage boxes for key:value pairs — you specify any number of these when creating a link (creating a link is what happens behind the scenes with the `deepview()` call), and then Branch takes care of returning that data to you after the app launches.

The `$deeplink_path` parameter is special, because in addition to being returned when the app launches, the Branch SDK will detect it and (on Android and iOS < 9) automatically attempt to load that URI destination. *However,* this parameter is still contained within the link and all that logic happens on the other end, rather than as the path that will be fired when your mobile website loads.

Comment: Seems a bit strange to me. Wouldn't it have been easier if you had just redirected the user to the scheme defined in the deepview link?

Comment: Not at all, in fact! Far more complicated to handle edge cases that way since that doesn't work for all browsers, and besides that would make deferred deep linking impossible